# Save user entry after validation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I enter in data on the create method and the user's data isn't valid, the user's inputs are not saved after `render 'new'`. I would like the invalid user inputs to be saved. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this?

On a side note, my ContactForm object is not linked to anything on a database, which is why I'm not using save?.

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @contact_form = ContactForm.new
   end

   def create
      @contact_form = ContactForm.new(params[:contact_form])

      if @contact_form.valid? && verify_recaptcha(model: @contact_form , message: EBM::RECAPTCHA_ERROR)
         redirect_to contact_create_path
      else
         render :action => 'new'
      end 
   end
end
```

Edit: refactored based on mind.blank's suggestions. Doesn't fix the problem though.

Edit2: Added view:

```
<div id="quote" class="hero-unit centerpiece">
   <form action="/contact" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
      <fieldset>

     <!-- Form Name -->
     <h1 class="form-header">Contact Us</h1>
     <!-- Text input-->
     <%= render 'shared/error', object: @contact_form %>
     <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Your Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
           <input id="name" name="contact_form[name]" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="input-xlarge"  >

        </div>
     </div>

     <!-- Text input-->
     <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Your Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
           <input id="email" name="contact_form[email]" type="text" placeholder="Your Email" class="input-xlarge" required="" >
        </div>
     </div>

     <!-- Textarea -->
     <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Your Message</label>
        <div class="controls">                     
           <textarea id="Your Message" class="message-area" name="contact_form[user_message]" required=""></textarea>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="recaptcha">
        <%= recaptcha_tags %>
     </div>
     <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
      </fieldset>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your view?

Comment: @alexBrand Just added it.

Comment: You are not using rails helpers to create your form. Your input fields are basically hard coded and rails has no way of filling the input fields.

Comment: That's probably the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this blog post on creating a contact form: http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `Hash.new` from your `new` action:

```
def new
  @contact_form = ContactForm.new
end
```

Also you can use `slice` to get the params required:

```
def create
  @contact_form = ContactForm.new(params.slice(:name, :email, :user_message))
  ...
end
```

Although usually you can just pass in `params[:contact_form]`

Comment: I refactored the code in the question based on your answer, and made the corresponding view changes. Unfortunately it didn't fix my problem.